# Placeholders for cshtml --- ASP.NET

Tags: web-application, appsec, sql-injection, asp.net

I'm learning Application Security, and tutorials such as www.asp.net discuss updating databases with placeholders, instead of directly using user input

```
@{
    var title = "";
    var genre = "";
    var year = "";
    var movieId = "";

    if(IsPost){
        Validation.RequireField("title", "You must enter a title");
        Validation.RequireField("genre", "Genre is required");
        Validation.RequireField("year", "You haven't entered a year");
        Validation.RequireField("movieid", "No movie ID was submitted!");

        title = Request.Form["title"];
        genre = Request.Form["genre"];
        year = Request.Form["year"];
        movieId = Request.Form["movieId"];

        if(Validation.IsValid()){
            var db = Database.Open("WebPagesMovies");
            var updateCommand = "UPDATE Movies SET Title=@0, Genre=@1, Year=@2 WHERE Id=@3";
            db.Execute(updateCommand, title, genre, year, movieId);
            Response.Redirect("~/Movies");
       }
    }
}
```

I'm confused. Aren't you still taking in userdata? I am trying to find an example of non-safe code that doesn't use placeholders, but all I get is "validate user input"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A more common term for this is "parameterized SQL".  You are still taking user data, as you pointed out, but the security lies in the fact that the application *knows* what is data, and what is executable.

When you build a SQL statement as a string and pass it in it's completed entirety to the database, the application simply has to trust that the SQL command being executed is what you intended, and has not be maliciously modified by user data during construction.

When the user data is passed in separately from the SQL statement as parameters and parameter values, the SQL command *can't* be directly modified by user input...It's separate.  The application can tell absolutely what is supposed to be executable, and that nothing in the parameter values should be...It's all data, and only data.

Answer (score 5):

To expand on Xander's answer - when you use a parameterized query the parameters are never inserted directly into the statement.  Instead, the query itself along with all of the parameters are passed to a stored procedure called `sp_executesql`.  When executed this way the parameters are treated as data rather than being parsed out as part of a SQL statement, so Injection is not possible (unless you are using dynamic sql or something).

This also gives you the added bonus of using cached execution plans which can help with performance.

If you are looking for examples of unsafe SQL the code below is an example:

```
var updateCommand = "UPDATE Movies SET Title='" + title + "', Genre=@0, Year=@1 WHERE Id=@2";
db.Execute(updateComman, genre, year, movieId);
```

In this example, you could inject through the `title` variable.

Comment: so in other words, a person can insert `'Frozen;Drop SQL Table'` when entering the title, but same attack would be defeated if we used placeholder for title value, i.e. `title=@`

Comment: I don't think your attack is quite right, but yes.  Someone could pass in an attack string as part of the title and it would work in my example but not if title is a parameter.  Also - notice that I said `parameter` not `placeholder`.  This is typically how people refer to what we are talking about.

Comment: @Glowie http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: @DanA. oh goodness!!!!